# Simplifying $1 -2\sin^2(10x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been looking at this trig identity for half an hour now.
The question:

> Simplify:  $1 -2\sin^2(10x)$

The answer: $\cos^2(20x)$

Could someone please explain to me the steps taken to get this answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong.

You have, for all $x$:

$$\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=2\cos^2-1=1-2\sin^2x$$

*You don't need all these equalities here, but as they are all useful and all derive from $\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a\sin b$, I think it's worth writing all of them.*

Now, $1-2\sin^2(10x)=\cos (20x)$. No square. And of course no square, as $1-2\sin^2(10x)$ is negative for some values of $x$ (take $x=\pi/20$ for instance)